# Redireccionar pagina despues de abrir archivo pdf en otra pestaña

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, ajax

Buenas espero puedan ayudarme, estoy utilizando barryvdh/laravel-dompdf para poder crear los pdf que necesita el sistema de reportes, ahora necesito realizar una redirección de la página donde se oprime el botón para crearlo, los metodos que se han usado solo generan el pdf en otra pestaña, pero no redirecciona o redireccionan pero no genera el pdf. Adjunto parte del codigo.

Agradeceria toda la ayuda que puedan brindar para poder solventar esta disyuntiva. Si necesitan mas información de reelevancia me lo indican.

```
 //============================ imprimir factura ============================
public function imprimir_factura(Request $request)
{
    if($request->person_id != null){
        if($request->factura != null){

            $billing = billing::find($request->factura);
            $billing->person_id = $request->person_id;
            $billing->type_payment_id = $request->tipo_pago;
            $billing->type_currency = $request->tipo_moneda;
            $billing->save();
            $fecha = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');

            $todos = Billing::with('person','employe.person','employe.doctor', 'patient', 'procedure','typepayment' , 'typecurrency')->where('id',$billing->id)->first();
            $total = 0;
            foreach($todos->procedure as $proce) { 
                $total += $proce->price;
            }

            $cirugia = Itinerary::with('person','employe.person','surgery.typesurgeries')->where('patient_id', $todos->patient_id )->where('employe_id',$todos->employe_id)->first();

            if($cirugia->surgery != null){
                $total_cancelar = $cirugia->surgery->typesurgeries->cost + $todos->employe->doctor->price + $total;
            }else{
                $total_cancelar = $todos->employe->doctor->price + $total;
            }

            $pdf = PDF::loadView('dashboard.checkout.print', compact('todos','cirugia','total_cancelar','fecha'));

            return $pdf->stream('factura.pdf');
        }else{
            Alert::error('No puede procesar la factura');
            return redirect()->back();
        }
    }else{
        Alert::error('No puede procesar la factura');
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}

    <form action="{{ route('checkout.imprimir_factura') }}" method="POST" target="_blank">
    @csrf 
    <div class="section-body py-3 row">
        <div class="section-body py-3 col-10 ml-5 ">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <!-----------------------Campos ocultoss---------------------->
                    <input id="person_id" type="hidden" name="person_id" value="" >
                    <input type="hidden" name="factura" value="{{ $crear_factura->id }}" >
                    <!-------------------- fin de Campos ocultoss------------------>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade active show" id="Invoice-detail" role="tabpanel">
                        <div class="row clearfix">
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-body row my-8  pl-4">
                                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12"><h2>Factura</h2> </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 d-flex justify-content-end pr-3 pt-10" style="color:#000" >
                                            <span class="h6 h66 pt-0 pr-10">Fecha:</span><span class="text col-lg-4 col-md-7 col-sm-12" style="margin-bottom:50px"><i class="fa fa-calendar pl-20"></i> {{ $fecha }}</span><br>
                                        </div>                             
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-body mt-0 " style="top:-50px">
                                    <!--Paciente-->
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12 mb-2">
                                                <span class="h6 h66"><i class="fa fa-user mr-2" style="font-size:18px"></i>Paciente:</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <input type="hidden" id="paciente_id" name="paciente_id" value="{{ $itinerary->person->id }}">
                                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12 pr-10 mb-2">
                                                <span id="dni" class="text form-control p-1 mt-0 text-left"><i class="fa fa-address-card"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ $itinerary->person->dni }}</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12 mb-2">
                                                <span id="name" class="text form-control p-1 text-left"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ $itinerary->person->name }} {{ $itinerary->person->lastname }}</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12 mb-2">
                                                <span id="phone" class="text form-control p-1 text-left"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ $itinerary->person->phone }}</span><br>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                    <!--Medico tratante-->
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12 mb-2">
                                                <span class="h6 h66"><i class="fa fa-user-md mr-2" style="font-size:18px"></i>Medico tratante:</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12 pr-10 mb-2">
                                                <span class="text form-control p-1 text-left"><i class="fa fa-address-card"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ $itinerary->employe->person->dni }}</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12 pr-10 mb-2">
                                                <span class="text form-control p-1 text-left"><i class="fa fa-user-md"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ $itinerary->employe->person->name }} {{ $itinerary->employe->person->lastname }}</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12 pr-10 mb-2">
                                                <span class="text form-control p-1 text-left"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ $itinerary->employe->person->phone }}</span><br>
                                            </div>
                                        </div><br>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-12 mt-2 d-flex justify-content-center">
                                                    <span class="h6 h66">Seleccione persona a pagar</span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-12 mt-2 d-flex justify-content-center">
                                                <div class="col-6 d-flex justify-content-end" >
                                                        <a class="btn btn-boo " title="Paciente" style="color:#fff" id="paciente" name="paciente"> 
                                                            <i class="fa fa-user mr-2"></i> Paciente
                                                        </a>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-6">
                                                            <a  class="btn btn-boo " title="Agregar cliente" style="color:#fff" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#otro"> 
                                                            <i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Otro cliente
                                                        </a>
                                                    </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div><br>
                                        <!--Persona a cancelar-->
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12 mb-2 mt-2">
                                                <span class="h6 h66"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart mr-1" style="font-size:18px"></i> Pagado por:</span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12 mb-2 mt-2">
                                                <span class="text form-control p-1"><i class="fa fa-address-card pl-1"></i>&nbsp;<span id="dni_c" class="text text-left"></span></span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12 mb-2 mt-2">
                                                <span class="text form-control p-1"><i class="fa fa-user pl-1"></i>&nbsp;<span id="name_c" class="text text-left"></span><span id="lastname_c" class="text text-left"></span></span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12 mb-2 mt-2">
                                                <span class="text form-control p-1"><i class="fa fa-phone pl-1"></i>&nbsp;<span id="phone_c" class="text text-left"></span></span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <!--tipo de moneda-->
                                        <div class="row mt-4">
                                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                                                <span class="h6 h66">Tipo de moneda:</span>
                                                <div class="form-group multiselect_div mt-2">
                                                    <select id="single-selection" name="tipo_moneda" class="multiselect multiselect-custom" style="display: none;">
                                                        @foreach ($tipo_moneda as $moneda)
                                                        <option value="{{ $moneda->id }}">{{ $moneda->name }}</option>
                                                        @endforeach
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <!--tipo de pago-->
                                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                                                <span class="h6 h66">Tipo de pago:</span>
                                                <div class="form-group multiselect_div mt-2">
                                                    <select id="single-selection2" name="tipo_pago" class="multiselect multiselect-custom" style="display: none;">
                                                        @foreach ($tipo_pago as $pago)
                                                        <option value="{{ $pago->id }}">{{ $pago->name }}</option>
                                                        @endforeach
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <!--Modal-->
                                        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                                <div class="modal-content">
                                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                    </button>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                                    ...
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="table-responsive push">
                                            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover mt-5">
                                                <tbody style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000">
                                                    <td colspan="5" class="text-left pl-4" style="font-weight:bold; ">DESCRIPCION</td>
                                                    <td class="text-right" style="width: 4%; font-weight:bold">COSTO</td>
                                                </tbody>
                                                @if($itinerary->employe->doctor != null)
                                                    <tbody style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000">
                                                        <td colspan="5" class="text-left pl-4">Consulta Médica</td>
                                                        <td class="text-right" style="width: 1%">{{ $itinerary->employe->doctor->price }}</td>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                @endif
                                                @if($procedure != 0)
                                                <tbody>
                                                    @foreach ($procedure as $item)
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td colspan="5" class="text-left pl-4">
                                                            <div class="text-muted">Procedimiento {{ $item->name }}</div>
                                                        </td>

                                                        <td class="text-right" style="width: 1%">{{ $item->price }}</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    @endforeach
                                                </tbody> 
                                                @endif
                                                @if($itinerary->surgery != null)
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td colspan="5" class="text-left pl-4">
                                                            <div class="text-muted">Cirugía {{ $itinerary->surgery->typesurgeries->name }}</div>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td class="text-right" style="width: 1%">{{ $itinerary->surgery->typesurgeries->cost }}</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody> 
                                                @endif
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td colspan="5" class="font600 text-right">Subtotal</td>
                                                    <td class="text-right" id="subtotal">{{ $total }}</td> 
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr class="bg-boo text-light">
                                                    <td colspan="5" class="font700 text-right ">Total a cancelar</td>
                                                    <td class="font700 text-right" id="costo_total">{{ $total }}</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </div><br>
                                        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-end">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-boo pr-5 pl-5 mr-3" onclick="redirect()"> <i class="fa fa-print"> </i> Imprimir</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Veo que eres nuevo en la comunidad, te sugiero publicar el código en lugar de imágenes ya que es mucho más útil. por otra parte te sugiuero leer [ask].

Comment: perfecto amigo voy a publicar el codigo

Comment: Quita las imágenes y publica todo el código en texto, no solo el php